# Confusion between the RSpec before/after hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been working with RSpec 3 for a few days and I realized I don't fully understand the before/after hooks that are provided.

My confusion is in 2 areas -

1. The various hook parameters available - `:suite`, `:context`, `:example`, `:all`, `:each` (am I missing any?). The first 3 appear to be new, as I've only ever seen the last two. Are the last two now deprecated and replace by the others?
2. The scope that each of the above covers -

   - I'm guessing `before(:context)` and `before(:example)` run once before each `context` block and individual example.
   - Does `before(:suite)` run once before ALL examples in a give `_spec` file?
   - Does each `before(:xxx)` block apply to only the contexts and examples at its own nesting level and below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), `:context` and `:example` are aliased as `:all` and `:each` in rspec3.

> Note: the :example and :context scopes are also available as :each and
>   :all, respectively. Use whichever you prefer.

The `before :suite` scope is executed first and then the `:context` and `:example` scopes:

```
before :suite
before :context
before :example
after  :example
after  :context
after  :suite
```

Beyond that, I'd recommend reading the documentation, which includes working examples of specific testing scenarios.